# I am getting an error while connecting Azure Devops with ADF Verify that your Azure DevOps account is connected to the AAD account,

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am not able to connect Azure Devops with ADF. i am getting an error as mentioned in screenshot
[image]

there is no repository coming when i clicked on select repo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Azure DevOps account is connected to your Azure AD tenant where the user from which you’re accessing ADF. By default, the Azure DevOps account gets created in Microsoft Tenant, Switch your Azure DevOps tenant to your Azure AD default directory and add the user account to that organization.

***Log in to your Azure DevOps organization > right side > Click on your profile > My profile> Switch your Directory from Microsoft account to Default directory like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Now, Create one organization and Project to import your Data-Factory repository. In the same Azure DevOps organization check if it’s connected to your Azure AD directory successfully like below:-

[image]

Now, connect to Azure DevOps git repo with Azure Data factory like below:-

[image]

[image]

Azure Data factory got connected to the git repository successfully like below:-

[image]

Connecting with azure devops repository link [Use repository link]

[image]

Got connected to the repository successfully like below:-

[image]

In your Azure DevOps organization make sure the user with whom you’re connecting git in ADF has required roles assigned on the repositories.

[Set Git repository permissions - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi Siddhesh i am not able to connect with AAD also i raised this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435034/i-am-getting-an-error-while-connecting-aad-in-azure-devops

Comment: sadly this answer is not valid for azure synapse  ... still get error message `Verify that your Azure DevOps account is connected to the AAD account, the Azure DevOps repository is in the Default Directory (foo-0ba9-45e9-b154-bar) tenant, and that your current ADF user account has been added to the Azure DevOps organization`  even though I do have setup what the error is asking for

Comment: @ScottStensland Can you check the answer provided in this Stack Post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435034/i-am-getting-an-error-while-connecting-aad-in-azure-devops > It is related to the same error code you're facing