# I am getting an error while connecting AAD in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am getting an error while connecting with AAD
User bhavyaaggarwal1993@outlook.com is a guest in the target AAD tenant Default Directory. The current organization policy does not allow guest users to access the organization. Change the policy setting to allow external guest access and try again.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Azure DevOps Directory is connected to the same Default directory as your Azure AD tenant. refer to below:-

When I try to connect my Azure DevOps organization connected to Microsoft account Tenant like below, I get the same error code as yours:-

***Log in to your Azure DevOps account click on your profile at right > My profile*** and check if your Microsoft Account is selected like below:-

[image]

When I visit the Azure DevOps organization part of this Microsoft account directory and try connecting my Azure AD tenant to this Azure DevOps organization, I get the **same error code as yours** like below:-

[image]

Make sure you change your Azure DevOps account directory to your Azure AD default directory like the below:-

***Click on My profile***

[image]

***Change the Directory to your Azure AD Default Directory like the below:-***

[image]

***If there’s no Organization > Create one and Check your Organization settings > Azure Active Directory***

[image]

*Your Azure DevOps account will be **connected** to your **Azure AD tenant** like the below:-*

[image]

By default, your bsaf-sgi-germany organization might be created inside Microsoft Account or another Directory than your Azure AD, change the Directory to Default like above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the real question is: Can I connect/transfer my ADO project in the "Microsoft Account" directory to the Default Directory? 
PS: I started working there and now I cannot connect to AAD. I have enough work there and I would not like a fresh start if I can transfer somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing my account type to a member in Microsoft Entra ID. See the [convert a Microsoft Entra guest into a member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-convert-an-azure-ad-guest-into-a-member).